# Drupal: Way to detect if a certain .tpl file is being used?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a site that uses a module that uses 2 .tpl files, eg: `list.tpl` and `product.tpl`. A 3rd .tpl file, `product-image.tpl`, is used within each of these and is called with a render function, eg:

On list.tpl:

```
<div id="list-images">
  <?php print render($element['productImage']);?>
</div>
```

and on product.tpl:

```
<div id="product-images">
  <?php print render($element['productImage']);?>
</div>
```

I want to modify the output of `product-image.tpl` when it displays on `product.tpl`. For example, something along the lines of:

> "If I am being used on product.tpl do this {..."

Would anyone know of a way to have `product-image.tpl` know what .tpl it is being used on?

Comment: I don't know much about drupal but can you simply add `<?php error_log('++++++++++ IT WAS CALLED!'); ?>`

Comment: @mkaatman to where, sorry?

Comment: Anywhere in those templates.

Comment: @mkaatman, ah, all the templates work - that's fine. I just want to distinguish when `product-image.tpl` is being called on `product.tpl`

Comment: @MeltingDog I think you can pass a variable to template using the render function then use the variable inside the product-image template to condition your output.

Comment: @ParantapParashar ah yes, I think that's similar to what I ended up doing.

Comment: @MeltingDog Yes. It looks like it. But I do not think it is a standard way of passing a variable into drupal template. It uses some pre-processors for that. But maybe I am wrong as I am not that familiar with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda got this working, but it's not the most elegant way.

On `product.tpl` I added a new elemet to the $element array:

```
<div id="product-images">
  <?php $element['productImage']['singleProd'] = true; ?>
  <?php print render($element['productImage']);
</div>
```

This allowed me to detect a difference later on when I used that array.

So, back on `product-image.tpl`:

```
if (!empty($element['singleProd'])){
   //do the things needed for product.tpl
}
else {
  //do the things needed for list.tpl
}
```

If anyone knows of a better way I would still be glad to hear it.

Comment: in Drupal, templates have a preprocess functions that sets up the variables that are sent to a template. Logic is meant to be done in the preprocess functions to keep your templates free of php/logic. It is not really enforced in Drupal 7 as it uses phptemplate, Drupal 8 is a different story as it uses twig.

Comment: If you ever want to see which templates are being used, just add `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` to your settings.php and comments will be output in the html showing which template files were used.